# Show that $f(x)$ is Riemann - Integrable using the Cauchy Criterion for integrability

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Cauchy - Criterion for integrability: A bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is Riemann-ntegrable iff for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P_{\varepsilon}$ such that $U(f, P_{\varepsilon}) - L(f, P_{\varepsilon}) < \varepsilon$

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$ on $I = [0, c]$, $c>0$. note that $f$ is decreasing on $I$. We want to show that $f$ is Riemann-integrable using the Cauchy criterion, i.e. for $\varepsilon > 0$, we must find a partition $P_{\varepsilon}$ such that $U(f, P_{\varepsilon}) - L(f, P_{\varepsilon}) < \varepsilon$.

If $0 < \varepsilon < c$, I tried $P_{\varepsilon} = \{0, \varepsilon, c\}$ but

$$U(f, P_{\varepsilon}) - L(f, P_{\varepsilon}) = (\varepsilon + \frac{c - \varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon}) - (\frac{\varepsilon}{1 + \varepsilon} + \frac{c - \varepsilon}{1 + c}),$$

which is messy and complicated.

As for $0 < c < \varepsilon$, I'm not even sure where to begin.

Any hints on how to partition $I$? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the values $j\varepsilon$, $j=1,2,3,\dots,N$.  Then make a partition $P = \{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N\}$ so that $f(x_j) = j\varepsilon$.  The point is that the upper and lower sums are within $\varepsilon$ of each other.

Comment: for each $j$, $f(x_{j}) = \frac{1}{1 + x_{j}} = j\varepsilon \implies x_{j} = \frac{1}{j \varepsilon} - 1$.

Comment: how do mi guarantee that $x_{j} = \frac{1}{j \varepsilon} - 1 \in [0,b]$?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers, @860009898987?

Answer (score 0):

For $n \in \mathbb N$ let $P:=\{\frac{j}{n}c: j=0,....,n\}.$

Show that

$$U(f, P)- L(f, P)= \frac{c}{n}(1- \frac{1}{c+1}).$$

If $ \varepsilon>0$ is given, then choose $n$ such that

$$\frac{c}{n}(1- \frac{1}{c+1} ) < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: $U(f,P) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} (\frac{1}{1 + \frac{(j-1)c}{n}})(\frac{c}{n}) = c \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+cj-c}$

Comment: $L(f,P) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} (\frac{1}{1 + \frac{jc}{n}})(\frac{c}{n}) = c \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+cj}$

Comment: $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = c \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+cj-c} - c \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+cj} = c^2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+cj-c)(n+cj)}$

Comment: That's what i obtained. how did you get $\frac{c}{n} (1 - \frac{1}{c+1})$?